# Jenkins tutorial maven project (with Docker) fails at Build stage

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I'm using the current Jenkins Maven Project tutorial using Docker:

https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/

I keep getting this error at the Build stage:

> [simple-java-maven-app] Running shell script
>
> sh: can't create
>   /var/jenkins_home/workspace/simple-java-maven-app@tmp/durable-bae402a9/jenkins-log.txt:
>   nonexistent directory
>
> sh: can't create
>   /var/jenkins_home/workspace/simple-java-maven-app@tmp/durable-bae402a9/jenkins-result.txt:
>   nonexistent directory

I've tried setting least restrictive permissions with `chmod -R 777`, `chown -R nobody` and `chown -R 1000` on the listed directories, but nothing seems to work.

This is happening with the jenkins image on Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6 on Windows 10 Professional.

As this is happening with the Maven project tutorial on the Jenkins site, I'm wondering how many others have run into this issue.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la /var/jenkins_home/workspace/simple-java-maven-app@tmp/` ?

Comment: That directory is empty; this is the output:


drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan 20 21:06 .

drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Jan 20 19:12 ..

I had permissions set as jenkins:jenkins and nobody:nobody before changing it back to root:root on all of /var and its subfolders

Comment: Which step of the tutorial are you on? Did you get any error messages earlier in the tutorial? If so, what and where?

Comment: Step 5 of "Create your initial Pipeline as Jenkinsfile" where you're actually running the Pipeline.  It fails at the Build step.

Answer (score 3):

I had also the same problem on MacOSX.
After few hours of research, I have finally find the solution.

To solve the problem, it's important to understand that Jenkins is inside a container and when the docker agent inside this container talk to your docker engine, it give path to mount volume matching inner the container. But your docker engine is outer. So to allow to work correctly path inner the container must match the same path outer the container in your host.

To allow working correctly, you need to change 2 things.

- docker run arguments
- Jenkinsfile docker agent arguments

For my own usage, I used this

```
docker run -d \
  --env "JENKINS_HOME=$HOME/Library/Jenkins" \
  --restart always \
  --name jenkins \
  -u root \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v $HOME/Library/Jenkins:$HOME/Library/Jenkins \
  -v "$HOME":/home \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

In the Jenkinsfile

Replace the agent part

```
agent {
  docker {
    image 'maven:3-alpine'
    args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
  }
```

by

```
agent {
  docker {
    image 'maven:3-alpine'
    args '-v <host_home_path>/.m2:/root/.m2'
  }
```

Comment: Frederic, thanks for the feedback.  I think this is on the right track, I think it has something to do with the short-lived maven container either having the wrong path mapping or perhaps not having the required permissions.  

I did try your suggested mapping values and it does not seem to have solved the problem in my case (as yet), but then I'm on Windows 10 and maybe I'm not putting the mapped path value in correctly.  I will keep you posted.

Comment: I'm not a specialist of windows and never used docker in Windows. So symlinks in windows doesn't have the same manner like on unix system. But you can try to use the embedded ubuntu with windows 10 offering bash and you access the NTFS like a unix system. and you manage everything like a unix system. A friend will invest with windows and will tell me.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely that this issue resulted from a recent change in Docker behaviour, which was no longer being handled correctly by the Docker Pipeline plugin in Jenkins.

Without going into too much detail, the issue was causing Jenkins to no longer be able to identify the container it was running in, which results in the errors (above) that you encountered with these tutorials.

A new version (1.15) of the Docker Pipeline plugin was released yesterday (https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow).

If you upgrade this plugin on your Jenkins (in Docker) instance (via **Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins**), you'll find that these tutorials should start working again (as documented).

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the directory `durable-bae402a9` was not created.

Walk back through the tutorial to find the step that should have created that directory, and make whatever changes are needed to make sure it succeeds.

Comment: That directory is created "on the fly" each time the Pipeline runs.  And apparently the part of that directory name which follows "durable-" changes each time the pipeline runs, so I can't even create it ahead of time.  It appears that whatever process tries to create it doesn't have proper permissions perhaps.  I've tried to assign the most permissive chmod (777) and chown (e.g. nobody:nobody) values on every directory above it, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Please look in the logs of whichever process is supposed to create the directory "durable-" for clues.